# Cannot deserialize (convert) unwrapped list when it's second in class using Jackson XmlWrapper

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I am trying to use XmlMapper from Jackson to deserialize some simple xml files containing unwrapped lists.

My code:

```
package zm.study.xmlserialize.jackson;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper    ;

public class JacksonListTest {

    public static class A {
        public String c;
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
        public List<String> as;
    }

    @Test
    public void deserializeTest() throws Exception
    {
        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        String xml = "<A><c>c</c><as>a1</as><as>a2</as></A>";
        //mapper.readValue(xml, A.class);
        mapper.convertValue(mapper.readTree(xml), A.class);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately the library raises an exception when doing so when the list is not first in class/xml.

The exception goes away when I remove the "c" element from xml and the class.
The exception also goes away if I use readValue instead of convertValue but I need the convertMethod to work.

The exception is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of VALUE_STRING token
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 18] (through reference chain: zm.study.xmlserialize.jackson.JacksonListTest$A["as"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343)
```

...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure it is possible to do that in this way. `readTree` method returns object which extends `JsonNode`, in that case it will be `ObjectNode`. `ObjectNode` does not accept two properties with the same name, and finally after deserialisation it represents:

```
{"c":"c","as":"a2"}
```

After that you want to convert this node to `A` `POJO` class. Default deserialiser for `List` expects `START_ARRAY` token not `String`. You can make it work by implementing custom converter which extends `StdConverter<String, List>` but list will be trimmed to one element. In that case, I think, you have to use `readValue` method because you need to instruct `Jackson` that `as` elements are unwrapped array.

**EDIT**
After your comment I realised we can trick `XmlMapper` to use whatever we want. It is pretty obvious that `Jackson` uses `JsonNodeDeserializer` to deserialise `JsonNode`-s. So, all we need to do is to find a place where we can inject our code. Fortunately there is a method `_handleDuplicateField` which handles our case. By default it throws exception if `FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY` flag is enabled:

```
protected void _handleDuplicateField(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt,
        JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory,
        String fieldName, ObjectNode objectNode,
        JsonNode oldValue, JsonNode newValue)
    throws JsonProcessingException
{
    // [databind#237]: Report an error if asked to do so:
    if (ctxt.isEnabled(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY)) {
        ctxt.reportInputMismatch(JsonNode.class,
                "Duplicate field '%s' for ObjectNode: not allowed when FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY enabled",
                fieldName);
    }
}
```

So, let's use this fact and extend this class:

```
class MergeDuplicateFieldsJsonNodeDeserializer extends JsonNodeDeserializer {
    @Override
    protected void _handleDuplicateField(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt, 
                                         JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory, String fieldName, ObjectNode objectNode, 
                                         JsonNode oldValue, JsonNode newValue) throws JsonProcessingException {
        super._handleDuplicateField(p, ctxt, nodeFactory, fieldName, objectNode, oldValue, newValue);

        ArrayNode array;
        if (oldValue instanceof ArrayNode) {
            // Merge 3-rd, 4-th, ..., n-th element to already existed array
            array = (ArrayNode) oldValue;
            array.add(newValue);
        } else {
            // Merge first two elements
            array = nodeFactory.arrayNode();
            array.add(oldValue);
            array.add(newValue);
        }
        objectNode.set(fieldName, array);
    }
}
```

Now, we need to register this deserialiser. Whole test could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JsonNodeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        a.c = "String";
        a.as = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "tom", "Nick");

        SimpleModule mergeDuplicatesModule = new SimpleModule("Merge duplicated fields in array");
        mergeDuplicatesModule.addDeserializer(JsonNode.class, new MergeDuplicateFieldsJsonNodeDeserializer());

        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(mergeDuplicatesModule);

        String xml = mapper.writeValueAsString(a);

        System.out.println(xml);
        System.out.println(mapper.readTree(xml));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
<A><c>String</c><as>1</as><as>2</as><as>tom</as><as>Nick</as></A>
{"c":"String","as":["1","2","tom","Nick"]}
```

Comment: I see. I think it would still be possible if by default the XmlMapper used ArrayNode and not ObjectNode and so wouldn't lose information in the process. Right now it seems the whole JsonNode api (which is quite an important part of the whole api) is useless with XML.

Comment: In `JSON` format it is pretty easy to figure out we are working with arrays because we have `[`. In `XML` it could be tickier. But end of all, we can always update internal implementation by our code and tell `Jackson` how to handle our case. I suggest to test my solution heavily because overloading internal classes always comes with some risk.

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue. Your edit seems to work for unwrapped lists but of course doesn't work for wrapped lists. I looked at the resultant JsonNode and the information is preserved so it looks like it could be done but it would have to be fixed on the convertTo part, I will see to it. I will submit your edit as a proposition of partial fix in Jackson GitHub.

Comment: I will mark it as answered because I can work with it. I can configure the mapper to always unwrap and if I need to handle wrapped lists, I will not rely on Jackson annotations but rather introduce another nesting level in Java model. I hope they will tackle this in the next Jackson release. Thx.

Comment: If you can configure your app to use many different versions of `ObjectMapper` instance maybe it will be easier for you. For one type of `POJO` classes with unwrapped list you can use above example, and for normal list you can use default `ObjectMapper`. It is also weird for me, that we have a problem like this. If you could, please provide `URL` to your issue on `GitHub` just for having reference for others devs with the same problem

Comment: I was getting made with this issue. Your proposed solution fixed the issue. The only thing is that I had to implement it for `com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.XmlMapper` and `corg.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode`, with some small trick, but it works fine. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code sample

This sample xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UsrAuthentRs>
 <Body>
  <BankUsrInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>901</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>902</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>903</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>904</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>905</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>906</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>907</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>908</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>909</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>910</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
     <RoleInfo>
        <RoleId>911</RoleId>
     </RoleInfo>
  </BankUsrInfo>
  </Body>
```

```
package com.inma.itp.queue.models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "UsrAuthentRs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UsrAuthentRs {


@XmlElement(name = "Body")
private Body body = new Body();

@Data
public static class Body {
    @XmlElement(name = "BankUsrInfo")
    private BankUsrInfo bankUsrInfo = new BankUsrInfo();


    @Data
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class BankUsrInfo {


        @XmlElement(name = "RoleInfo")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
        private List<RoleInfo> roles;


        @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        public static class RoleInfo {
            @XmlElement(name = "RoleId")
            private String roleId;

        }
    }
}

}
```

This main method which you can convert xml file to Pojo class

```
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
UsrAuthentRq deserializedData = xmlMapper.readValue(YouXmlHere, UsrAuthentRq.class);
```