# Using Jackson XmlMapper and readTree() to parse a XML file as JsonNode is ignoring xml element siblings

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have a simple XML file that has the following structure

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<EXPORT id="0" >
    <PUB id="1">
        <PGR id="2" name="siblingparent" >
            <PGR id="3" name="sibling1"/>
            <PGR id="4" name="sibling2"/>
        </PGR>
    </PUB>
</EXPORT>
```

I have this test to see if Jackson's `XmlMapper` using the  `readTree()` method will parse the file as `JsonNode` correctly.

```
  @Test
  public void test() throws IOException {
    JsonNode node = parser.getNodeFromXML(siblingXML.getFile());
    assertThat(node.findValues("PGR")).size().isEqualTo(3);
  }
```

The test fails because only `1` `PGR` element has been found.

This is the logic for `parser.getNodeFromXML`:

```
  public JsonNode getNodeFromXML(File xmlFile) throws IOException {
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    return xmlMapper.readTree(xmlFile);
  }
```

And this is how the `JsonNode` Object / the variable `node` in the test is returned:

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "PUB": {
    "id": "1",
    "PGR": {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "siblingparent",
      "PGR": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "sibling2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see only `sibling2` to has been parsed by the `XmlMapper`. I already looked for flags to allow siblings or whatever. Was not able to find a solution yet. May I misunderstand what a *Tree* is here? Does it ignore siblings on purpose?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but it could have something to do with duplicate same-level keys. In theory JSON allows that, but it would make sense to assume many serialization frameworks would prohibit it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object) for reference.

Comment: [Also related](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/60)

Comment: @Mena remove dot from the last link

Comment: `JsonNode` is not able to handle many properties with the same name. You need to introduce manual deserialisation or provide `POJO` class which fits your `XML` payload. Take a look on similar questions: [Cannot deserialize unwrapped list ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597977/cannot-deserialize-convert-unwrapped-list-when-its-second-in-class-using-jack), [Using Jackson to add XML attributes to manually-built node-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060797/using-jackson-to-add-xml-attributes-to-manually-built-node-tree)

Comment: Ok I understand. I was trying to reenable the duplicates but was not able to do so using the `XmlMapper#enable` method. It has a lot of features including exception throwing when a duplicate key occurs but unfortunately no way to disable it :(